# div gets pushed down on hover of images

Tags: html, css

I am using instafeed to pull in a few Instagram photos, and on hover I want the images' opacity to decrease and have text appear in the middle. I have it implemented, but once I hover over an image the entire div gets pushed down, and I can't figure out why.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/50n9aj5o/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="instafeed">
  <a href="http://instagram.com/p/uwEzRVQD76/" class="social--txt" target="_blank">
     <img src="//scontent-a.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/10724794_782098195161927_1323715061_a.jpg" class="social--img">
  </a>
  <a href="http://instagram.com/p/uwERhewD6y/" class="social--txt" target="_blank">
     <img src="//scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpf1/t51.2885-15/1738685_935644246450368_2120258613_a.jpg" class="social--img">
  </a>
  <a href="http://instagram.com/p/uvbUOSQo8h/" class="social--txt" target="_blank">
     <img src="//scontent-a.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/10727504_976335432382365_1290609468_a.jpg" class="social--img">
  </a>
  <a href="http://instagram.com/p/uvUdbFwoyF/" class="social--txt" target="_blank">
     <img src="//scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/10727771_591627530962949_254447269_a.jpg" class="social--img">
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a {
   text-decoration: none;
}

.social--txt {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}

.social--txt:hover::before {
   content: 'test';
   color:  black;
   font-weight: 500;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   left: 20%;
   text-align: center;
}

.social--img {
   width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
          transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}

.social--img:hover {
   filter: alpha(opacity=50);
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to social--txt

```
.social--txt {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
}
```

then change .social--txt:hover::before to `position: absolute;`

http://jsfiddle.net/50n9aj5o/4/